# need help dual booting Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7 (Ubuntu installed)

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows

I recently replaced Windows 7 Pro with Ubuntu 13.04. I did not partition the drives to install Windows on, because I do not know how. I did the full installation of Ubuntu, meaning I did not install alongside Windows. I still have my Windows 7 Pro dis. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Try checking this out this question... 
http://superuser.com/questions/86843/install-windows-7-after-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a NTFS formatted primary (sda1 thru sda4) partition with the boot flag.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows